# join table product and product option in external script

Tags: product, collection, join-table

i'm trying to join the products and product_option table by using this script

```
<?php

ini_set('memory_limit',"1000M");
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
set_time_limit(0);
define('MAGENTO', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php';

Mage::app();

    $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

    $_productCollection->getSelect()->join(array('mep' => "catalog_product_option"), "e.entity_id = mep.product_id", array('mep.*'));

    echo count($_productCollection);

?>
```

but it got errors:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id "29" already exist' in /home/m1/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php:373 Stack trace: #0 /home/m1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(265): Varien_Data_Collection->addItem(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)) #1 /home/m1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1055): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->addItem(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)) #2 /home/m1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(871): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_loadEntities(false, false) #3 /home/m1/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(752): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load() #4 [internal function]: Varien_Data_Collection->count() #5 /home/m1/public_html/product_options.php(24): count(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection)) #6 {main} thrown in /home/m1/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php on line 373
```

anyone knows what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento does not allow 2 items with the same id in a collection. And if you start with the product collection and join the option collection you will get duplicate ids if at least one product has 2 options.
You should try retrieving the options collection and join with the product collection.
The downside of this is that you get only products with options. and you won't get all the product attributes in the collection.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->join(array('mep' => "catalog_product_entity"), "e.product_id = mep.entity_id", array('mep.*'));
```